# Accessing TemplateField controls value of gridview inside button click handler in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

After clicking the edit linkbutton of my gridview, I show the data on different text boxes which are not inside the gridview. I have a "Reset" button which i want to use to get back to the original values. But I am having problem to access those gridview data inside the button click handler and reset it.I tried using DirectCast() but its showing System.NullReferenceException.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView3" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="id">
<Columns>
     <asp:TemplateField>
         <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:LinkButton ID="lblEdit" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="editRecord" Text="EDIT" CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>"></asp:LinkButton>
         </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="id" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="id" Visible="False">
        <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:Label ID="lblRecordID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("id") %>'></asp:Label>
         </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="HANGER">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblHANGER" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("HANGER") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns></asp:GridView>
```

The backend vb.net code is-

```
Protected Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnReset.Click
        Dim vID As Label = DirectCast(GridView3.SelectedRow.FindControl("lblRecordID"), Label)
        Dim vHanger As Label = DirectCast(GridView3.SelectedRow.FindControl("lblRecordID"), Label)
        txtID.Text.Text = vID.Text()
        ddlHanger.SelectedValue = vHanger.Text 'dropdown list that's why selectedValue used

End Sub
```

I have copied the portion of the code cause the gridview has lot more rows. I would appreciate if anyone please show me a solution.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using lblEdit anywhere in your code-behind?

Comment: @lucidgold im using the command "editRecord" inside the lblEdit in the code behind.

Answer (score 0):

First remove the following:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lblEdit" runat="server" CausesValidation="false"
         CommandName="editRecord" Text="EDIT" 
         CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>"></asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
```

And add:

```
<asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" ShowSelectButton="True" SelectText="EDIT" />
```

That markup will allow your GridView to have an *EDIT* button which will switch the current selected row index correctly. **System.NullReferenceException** error you are recieving could be because the GridView3.SelectedRow is NULL/EMPTY, which also means GridView3 currently has NO selected index.

To make sure that GrieView3 indeed selected a ROW, you can add: the following right **AFTER** the

```
<SelectedRowStyle BackColor="Black" BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="Dotted" 
                  BorderWidth="3px" ForeColor="White" />
```

right after

```
</Columns>
```

So your final GridView3 markup should look like:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView3" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="id">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" ShowSelectButton="True" 
                          SelectText="EDIT"  />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="id" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="id" Visible="False">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblRecordID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("id") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="HANGER">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblHANGER" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("HANGER") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="Black" BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="Dotted" 
                      BorderWidth="3px" ForeColor="White" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Then you can also use TryCast too, like so:

```
Protected Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnReset.Click
    Dim vID As String = TryCast(GridView3.SelectedRow.FindControl("lblRecordID"), Label).Text
    Dim vHanger As String = TryCast(GridView3.SelectedRow.FindControl("lblRecordID"), Label).Text

    txtID.Text.Text = vID
    ddlHanger.SelectedValue = vHanger
End Sub
```

Comment: I am not sure. How am i gonna use your example in my code? Because im am using gridview row command events and editing in separate panel where i am sending the gridview data.

Comment: Well if you post more of your code we can then figure out a good placement for this post asnwer. Are you still recieving System.NullReferenceException? All I suggested was to make sure you use ShowSelectButton="True" to make sure the GridView indeed has a selected row, so then you will no longer recieve NULL errors.

Comment: thanks. I'm actually doing the total process in a different way now.